# Aspas Simples no Access

Tags: sql, vba, excel-vba, microsoft-access

Tenho uma macro em Excel que lê os conteudos da célula e salva em banco de dados do tipo Access, quando tento inserir uma string que possua aspas simples no meio da string ela o seguinte erro: `FALTA DE OPERADOR NA CONSULTA`, exemplo de string:

João Sant'Ana

Segue o meu código em VBA para a inserção de dados

```
Private Sub btn_carregaJIRA_Click()

MsgBox ("JIRA")

Dim diretorio As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

'Variaveis do BD Access
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

'Parametrização do Banco de Dados
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
strDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AlocacaoBD.accdb"
cn.ConnectionString = _
          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strDB & ";"
'Abrindo conexão com o banco de dados
cn.Open

'Iniciando o FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Configurando o FileDialog
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Selecione o Arquivo do JIRA"

    If .Show = True Then
        fileName = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If
End With
   'Desabilitando o ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Abrindo o Arquivo
   Workbooks.Open (fileName)
    'Selecionando o arquivo
   Workbooks(fileName).Activate

    linhaJira = 2

    While Cells(linhaJira, 1) <> "Total"

    nomeTask = Cells(linhaJira, 1).Value
    programa = Cells(linhaJira, 2).Value
    epic = Cells(linhaJira, 3).Value
    atividadeTipo = Cells(linhaJira, 4).Value
    nomeColab = Cells(linhaJira, 5).Value
    mes = Month(Now()) - 1
    horaAloc = Cells(linhaJira, 6).Value
    jiraTec = fileName

    StrSql = "INSERT INTO Jira (jira_nomeTask,jira_Program,jira_Epic,jira_Tipo,jira_NomeColab, jira_Mes, jira_HoraAloc, jira_tec)" & _
        " Values ("" & nomeTask & "" ,'" & programa & "','" & epic & "','" & atividadeTipo & "', '" & nomeColab & "', '" & mes & "', '" & horaAloc & "', '" & jiraTec & "' )"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(StrSql)

    linhaJira = linhaJira + 1
    Wend
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
   MsgBox ("Sucesso! Foi Cadastrado: " & linhaJira)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver esse caso precisa duplicar as aspas, de forma a que o texto seja aceite pelo SQL.

Crie esta função:

```
Private Function TrataAspasSimples(ByVal strTexto As String)
    If InStr(strTexto, "'") > 0 Then
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "'", "''")
    End If

    TrataAspasSimples = strTexto
End Function
```

Depois onde precisar validar as aspas simples evoque a função:

```
programa = TrataAspasSimples(CStr(Cells(linhaJira, 2).Value))
epic = TrataAspasSimples(CStr(Cells(linhaJira, 3).Value))
atividadeTipo = TrataAspasSimples(CStr(Cells(linhaJira, 4).Value))
nomeColab = TrataAspasSimples(CStr(Cells(linhaJira, 5).Value))
horaAloc = TrataAspasSimples(CStr(Cells(linhaJira, 6).Value))
jiraTec = TrataAspasSimples(fileName)
```

O campo `mes` não coloquei porque é um campo numérico inteiro, não tem aspas.